# Textbox disabled does not send value to database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a text box which picks up a value from my database and is a read only text box. it contains some information which i want to send to my datbase but nothing is being recorded. Once the textbox isnt a read only, the data is successfully stored. Is there any way i can keep my textbox disabled and still send the data to my database?

```
<form action="refnoadded.php?public=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">        
    <span id="sprytextfield1">
        <input type="text" name="ref"  value="<?php echo $newpass ?>" disabled />    
        <input type="button" onClick="history.go(0)" value = "Generate Reference">
        <br />
        <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Reference Number Required</span>
    </span>        
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Add Reference" />
</form>
```

any ideas?

Comment: the question is: Why? if it's disabled, then you don't need to send it, surely?

Comment: i dont want the user to edit the data becuase i have a button next to it which randomly generates a few numbers and letters

Comment: Ah I see. you're using javascript to generate the few numbers? the new numbers are shown in the textbox?

Comment: the user might not be able to change the disabled or readonly input normally, but you can't rely on this. it's still easy to change the value using for instance firebug or just sending a customized form. never trust user data.

Comment: @Flukey yes but i am using php instead of javascript :)

Comment: This is nonsense question. what's the point in sending data back to the server when it is already there?

Answer (score 15):

disabled doesn't send data to server

use

```
<input readonly value="my value" name="myname">
```

HTH!

Comment: @OP - Be aware the user can still change the data in that textbox. Don't trust user input.

Answer (score 7):

have the data in a second hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ref_hidden" value="<?php echo $newpass ?>" />
```

the user won't see the difference and you will get your value send when submitting the form.

Answer (score 1):

Disabled textfields don't submit their information to $_POST or $_GET. You can simply use the form element

```
<input type="hidden" name="rev_hidden" value="<?php print $password; ?>" />
```

This is the standard (correct) way to pass hidden information in the form.

Another use for this element is if you want to pass a "formsubmitted" variable.

However, if you want to create a value and have it uneditable by the user, *do it on the server side*. Create the value when you create the database, since users can relatively-simply send other data in the place of what you've generated.